# Why are the scores so different for the two approaches (auto test using API interface and manual test)?

Tags: python, pagespeed-insights

We used two ways to test the score in PageSpeedInsight:
  - one is the manual test (open the PageSpeedInsight homepage, enter url, click the button to test)
  - the other is the auto test (call the interface of the API https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v4/run to auto test)

But we found an issue when we implement the auto test, the ruleGroups.(key).score value returned by interface is a quite difference from the value returned via manual test. And there is a strange case: the desktop ruleGroups.(key).score value returned by interface is very similar to the mobile score via the manual test.

Do you know why this happens? Could you please advise on it?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow!! It would be great if you could [read these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a new question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The page speed API is now on version 5 for Page Speed Insights website so if you want similar results you should use the same end-point (version 5 of PSI API).

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/reference/pagespeedapi/runpagespeed#response